# Problems with MYSQL trigger copying certain data to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

After hours of pulling my hair out I could do with a little help with a MYSQL trigger. I have two tables running logs. Let's say a 'master' and a 'slave'. When a log is entered into the 'master', if a string within a column meets a certain criteria I need certain values from that new row to be copied to a slave table.

This is the closest I have gotten so far...

```
CREATE TRIGGER `web_log_filter` AFTER INSERT ON `master` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF (NEW.criteria_column = 'criteriaX') THEN
        INSERT INTO slave (coulmn1,column2,column3) 
    VALUES(NEW.coulmn1,NEW.column2,NEW.column3);
    END IF;
END
```

It is currently returning a syntax error on line 5 and can't figure out why.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `DELIMITER`?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `web_log_filter` AFTER INSERT ON `master`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF (NEW.criteria_column = 'criteriaX') THEN
        INSERT INTO slave (coulmn1, column2, column3) 
            VALUES(NEW.coulmn1, NEW.column2, NEW.column3);
    END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't no! BUT now I have implemented that from your code, the DELIMITER give a syntax error